# US patents xsds

Tags: uspto

Is it possible to get US patents schema in xsd format. I could find it in dtd format at the folllowing location but not xsds.

[xml-resources](https://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/xml-resources)

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a final draft of ST.96 XML Schema](http://www.wipo.int/cws/en/taskforce/xml4ip/st96/cws2/st96-annex-iii.html)
Perhaps, there is everything that you want.

Comment: thank you.
There is one problem though with the schema while generating jaxb classes. xsd files import multiple xsds in the same namespace so it fails. e.g. the following:
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/Common/0" schemaLocation="../../../Common/0/Basic/id-V0-5.xsd"/>
 <xsd:import namespace="http://www.wipo.int/standards/XMLSchema/Common/0" schemaLocation="../../../Common/0/Basic/fileReferenceIdentifier-V0-1.xsd"/>

Just wondering if anybody faced similar issues.